# Getting error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token

Tags: c, algorithm

I am enrolled in Stanford's algorithms part-1 course and I am trying to implement a *quick find algorithm* in c.
Below is my code for implementing quick find.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define n 10
void union (int, int, int *);
void connected(int, int, int *);
int main(){ 

    //initializing array value to it's index value
    int i;
    int id[n];
    for(i = 0 ; i < n;i++)
    {
        id[i] = i;
    }
    union(0,5,id);
    union(3,4,id);
    union(5,8,id);
    connected(3,4,id);
    connected(0,8,id);

}

void union(int a, int b,int *p)
{
    int x, y;
    x = p[b];
    y=  p[a];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (p[i]==y)
            p[i] = x;
    }

}

void connected(int a, int b,int *p)
{
    if(p[a]==p[b])
        printf("connected");
    else
        printf("not connected");

}
```

Whenever I compile the program, the following errors are generated.

I have already checked my function prototypes and declarations but I am unable to find the problem.

```
quick_find.c:4:12: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
 void union (int, int, int *);
            ^
quick_find.c:4:6: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 void union (int, int, int *);
      ^
quick_find.c: In function ‘main’:
quick_find.c:15:7: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
  union(0,5,id);
       ^
quick_find.c:16:7: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
  union(3,4,id);
       ^
quick_find.c:17:7: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
  union(5,8,id);
       ^
quick_find.c: At top level:
quick_find.c:23:11: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
 void union(int a, int b,int *p)
           ^
quick_find.c:23:6: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 void union(int a, int b,int *p)
```

Comment: now look at your post on Stack Overflow: all those `union`s are coloured blue, unlike say `connected` which is in black. Dark blue means that it is a language keyword, not unlike `if` or `while`.

Comment: You are editing the code as you go along and invalidating answers.  That is VERY unfriendly.  Please stop doing that; SO is not a syntax/grammar removal tool.  Copy/paste your code and, if you wish to signal edits, APPEND the modified copy or ask another question!

Comment: I'd close this as typo of typos.

Comment: Edits are meant for adding new information that **clarifies** the question, *not changing it*. If you have a different question (particularly if the code changes), ask it **as a new question**. Changing the question using edit like you have is aweful because it desychronises the existing answers from the question, which makes those answers hard to stumble upon for future viewers. Please think of others when you edit. Adios...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the extra `{`

```
void union{(int a, int b,int *p)
          ^
```

---

**NOTE:** This answer was posted before the OP edited the question to remove the typo (mentioned in this answer). Check the [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37224202/revisions) for clarity.

---

**ANOTHER NOTE:** 
Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

Comment: I hope you're not serious...

Comment: @R.I.P.Seb ah this **was** another typo in the previous code.

Comment: So the question should be downvoted.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, Yup, OP edited the question after I posted.

Comment: The function call was origianlly 'void union{(int a, int b,int *p)',   The OP then removed the bracket, so making this answer look wrong:(  That is apart from the misuse of 'union'.

Comment: @MartinJames, should I delete the answer?

Comment: Up to you:)    As of now, you have one upvote.  I downvoted the question too because of the unfriendly edits.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala In that case, this gets a +1 from me for answering the question, and the question gets a -1 for changing the answer. Thanks for picking me up on that... and sorry for coming to a premature conclusion.

Comment: @R.I.P.Seb well, I did the same.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I'll just edit the answer to include information that this answers the unedited question that the OP posted in the beginning. It will not misguide the people visiting then.

Answer (score 8):

`union` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_reserved_keywords.htm), you can not use it as an identifier.

Comment: More generally,_you cannot use it as an identifier_.

Comment: Suggested solution: use unite as a function name, instead?